# How to display Israeli currency symbol in android?

Tags: android

I want to display Israeli currency symbol. 
I'm using this code to display currency. 
The problem is that Locale object does not have reference to Israeli currency (IL). 
Is there any workaround ?

```
NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US); 
double doublePayment = 100.13;
String s = n.format(doublePayment);
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code with unicode symbol:

```
System.out.println( s + "\u20AA");
```